# Compare two list Items using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object with the following Properties

```
public class Name
{
    public string FirstName 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

I get a list of Name Object as **NameList** which contains two objects as item

I want to compare these two objects in the list to get the object which has same **FirstName**. I have been looking for a solution for past 2 hours.

In the List of Name object I get two Name objects as

ListItem 1:  FirstName : Steve ; 
             LastName : Rogers;

ListItem 2 : 
             FirstName : Steve ; 
             LastName : David;

What i want is to compare these to list Items check if the FirstName Properties are same

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data Your question isn't quite clear. Are you saying you have List<Name> which contains just two Name objects? It isn't clear what you mean by "get the object which has same FirstName" because a single object can't have a "same firstname" (same as what?)

Comment: As per my understanding, I think you have a single list and you want to check items with same name inside that list. So you should try grouping...

Comment: I have updated the question. please check and let me know

Comment: @Eterm I think he has one list with some `Name` objects. He want to get all `Name` objects which has the same FirstName as another Listitem

Comment: Ok, so a group by then filtering the groups so they have count > 1 should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find all duplicates.

```
var duplicates = NameList.GroupBy(o => o.FirstName).Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any()).SelectMany(g => g);
```

Comment: Seems like you understood it wrong :)
OP made an edit, check it out

Comment: Please check the updated question. hope you understood the query

Comment: @Simon Updated answer to get all objects with duplicate firstnames.

Comment: @Midhun Please see updated solution. This gets all duplicates.

Comment: Sorry for Asking again.. is there any way to check this for immediate preceding listitem?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for now, but you can add an orderby, and/or a .FirstOrDefault() to get the first of the results

Comment: @Midhun "Preceding" is a very subjective concept. If you order by `FirstName` duplicates always follow one another. If, as you say, you only have two items in the list, a duplicate *always* precedes the other.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get all objects with the same FirstName you should be using GroupBy:

```
var groups = NameList.GroupBy(li => li.FirstName);
```